# Not too familiar with debugging in Xcode. Any idea why this exception is being thrown?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

[image]

Not too sure why I'm getting an exception. It's probably a pretty common error but, I honestly have no clue. Thanks for the help.

[image: This is with breakpoint on for all exceptions thrown.]

Above pic is from my main.m file

[image: Exception thrown]

Comment: I dont see any caught exception in the console did you step over the code? or set a breakpoint, then delete the breakpoint and screenshot?

Comment: I set the breakpoint at all exceptions so, I'm not too sure what's going on.

Comment: Press the "Play" button to see, if the debugger prints a 'real' error.

Comment: Shouldn't SIGABRT have a console output that tells me about the crash?

Comment: @sae SIGABRT in my main.m file int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}

Comment: @STANGMMX why not just let it run without any breakpoint and when the exception is caught, can you take a screenshot(the console area only) and i can see what i can do to help

Comment: So which of your view controllers is a subclass of UITableViewController? Maybe the one with the identifier "Main"? Or maybe this `initViewController`?

Comment: @STANGMMX did you use .xib? like for example initViewController.xib?

Comment: I think your view controller with identifier Main might be a UIViewController instead of the UITableviewController you are trying to instantiate?

Comment: @geraldWilliam yea thats what im thinking too or maybe he doesnt use initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style method

Comment: MenuViewController and MainViewController are both subclasses of UITableViewController.

Comment: As an aside, objective c classe names should start with a capital. Variables should start lower case

Comment: And you have set the class of the view controller in storyboard?

Comment: @geraldWilliam yeah my bad. used to write java, and frankly it's been wayyyy too long.

Comment: @STANGMMX Did you set tableView as delegate?

Comment: I had set MainViewController : UITableViewController rather than UIViewController. Doh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableViewControllers expect that their top-level view is a UITableView.

It looks like you have a UITableViewController (or a subclass of that) which has a top-level which **isn't** a UITableView. So check each top-level view in your storyboard.